# login doesnt direct to the page

Tags: php, mysql

my registration page redirects to the user profile but when I login it doesn't and they direct to the same page.  The registration is successful because I can see the user profile in my database. I am using a free webhosting serviceand could that be causing the problem although I dont really see why.  I am using PHP and mysql any advice to why it doesn't work would be amazing

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "password", "");

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($firstname)) { array_push($errors, "First name is required"); }
  if (empty($lastrname)) { array_push($errors, "Last name is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database for email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { 
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // register user 
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password 

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, firstname, lastname, ) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }
    else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

below is the code for my login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <header> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Oh Polly</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Roughly 155 characters">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Oh Polly</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="cart.php" class="navbar-right"><img src="cart-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="cartindex.php">Clothes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
</head>  

  <body>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

       <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-5">

                    <h1>Login</h1>

                    <p class="lead">Please enter your information to login.</p>

                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
                        <div class="messages"></div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="form_name">User Name</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your user name" required="required" data-error="Username is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_subject">Password *</label>
                    <input id="form_subject" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your password*" required="required" data-error="The password is required">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>        
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" name="login_user" value="Login">
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                <p>Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a></p>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
</form>


<style scoped>
.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    }
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}   
</style>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code to understand where things go wrong?

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion but the console on my webhost doesn't offer that and because of the database connection I can't really check.  If there is another way to debug? This a project for school and is the first time I have really ever worked with php.

Comment: You could add php and nysqli error reporting, you could do error handling and also orint out variables at different pkaces of the code to check status. SO has questions and answers on all these.

Comment: Nested forms is a no-no.